# Locking because of triggers mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have a memory table and I am updating it somewhere around 3000 updates per second. I setup a another table in Innodb and then created a Trigger so that all data can be send to the innodb table as a backup since memory table can disappear if server reboots.

My problem is I get errors like this Waiting for table level lock, from my show process list. I am unable to update Memory table anymore and all my operations blocked.

As soon as I delete these triggers no more locks and I can continue updating the tables.

Can anyone help with this, do I need to create triggers differently or some setting need to be changed ?

Comment: Can you post trigger[s] body ?

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER `account_bu` BEFORE UPDATE ON `accounts` FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE `account_innodb_table` SET
`name` = NEW.name,
`limit` = NEW.limit,
`money` = NEW.money,
`val` = NEW.val,
`conceal` = NEW.conceal
WHERE `id` = NEW.id;;

Comment: Such a trigger kind of defeats the purpose of keeping table in memory - each update ends up persisting in innodb table which causes many locks. If you can't avoid storing data in persistent table, I'd suggest to replace `UPDATE` statement in the trigger with `INSERT` . I mean adding a new table, say `pending_updates` where you insert all the changes (by the trigger), and a stored procedure that runs periodically and reads data from `pending_updates` (potentially aggregates it) , and updates main table.

Comment: Quick Question: Do you have MySQL Replication setup right now ???

Comment: yes we have few slaves that connects to this master

Answer (score 1):

In one situation, I found it possible to ingest data faster into InnoDB than into MEMORY.  Perhaps you should simply get rid of the MEMORY table and the TRIGGER.

I discuss that an many other tidbits in [my high-speed ingestion blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table).

Do you have multiple inserters?  Do you insert multiple rows in a single INSERT?  Are you pulling the data out of the MEMORY table?  How often, how, when, etc?  Is Replication involved?  Is "normalization" happening?  Summarization?